# How can we draw a line between two distant points using a finite-length ruler?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

We want to join by a line two distinct points $A$ and $B$. We have only a ruler of length $l>0$ and a pen. If $AB>l$ how can we do this?

Comment: we don't have a compass?

Comment: Can I fold the paper?

Comment: No, we don't have a compass, and we cannot fold paper. It's a plane geometry problem. We want to find an exact method. I'm trying to solve this by DESARGUE THEOREM and PROJECTIVE GEOMETRY.

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/188471/how-can-we-join-two-points-with-a-small-ruler

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is one instance of [Desargues' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27_theorem):

[image: Desargues]

Use the ruler to draw two arbitrary lines through $A$ in the general direction of $B$. You can extend them by simply shifting the ruler along the portion of the line you've already drawn. Once you're close to $B$, end the lines in points $C$ and $D$. On the line $CD$ choose a third point $E$, and through $E$ choose two more lines, one which intersects $AC$ in $F$ and $AD$ in $G$, the other which intersects $BC$ in $I$ and $BD$ in $H$. Now $GH$ and $FI$ intersect in a point on $AB$. If you have made the arbitrary choices in a suitable fashion, then all those lines could be drawn with your short ruler, and the resulting point $P$ will be closer to $A$ than $B$ was. Externd line $BP$ and it will reach $A$.

If any of the lines needed for this construction is too long, you may iteratively perform this whole construction there, or pick your points such that they lie closer together.

As an alternative, you might use [Pappos' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_hexagon_theorem) instead of [Desargues'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27_theorem). It requires one point and one line less, and on the whole looks somewhat more symmetric:

[image: Pappos]

As before, you start by drawing lines $AC$ and $AD$ in the general direction of $B$. You choose a point $E$ on $BC$ and a point $F$ on $BD$. Then you intersect $FC$ with $AD$ to obtain $G$ and $ED$ with $AC$ to obtain $H$. $EG$ and $FH$ will intersect in $P$ which lies on $AB$. Externd $BP$ and it reaches $A$, as before.

Comment: It is good when $AB-l$ is small, but when $AB>>l$ is a huge value, no one could guarantee that you can draw line as $BD$ or $CB$...

Comment: @Bogdan: If you notice your line $AC$ is too far away from $B$, then you can draw a new line closer to the actual line $AB$. Or you choose $F$ and $G$ arbitrarily, then draw their connections by recursively applying this whole idea until your ruler becomes sufficient. If you want to connect $A$ and $B$ using only one instance of Desargues' theorem, then you have to have points which connect to both $A$ and $B$. And I can't think of any way to add to Desargues' configuration which would help me avoid that problem.

Comment: A small typo: "the other which intersects $CD$ in $I$ and $BD$ in $H$" => "the other which intersects $BC$ in $I$ and $BD$ in $H$"

Comment: Also, "repeat as required" is not necessary - once you have the point $P$, you can simply extend $PB$ by chunks until you reach $A$.

Comment: @Mario: Thanks for pointing out the typo. The “repeat as required” might still be needed in an iterative fashion, if the lines I described to perform the construction are still too long to draw directly.

Comment: What i have to do after getting point P

Comment: @Soham: extend $BP$. I just edited my answer to clarify this aspect.