# How to draw the segment $[A,B] $ with only a ruler whose length is too short.

Tags: plane-geometry, geometric-construction

Given the points $ A $ and $ B $ in the plane. I have been asked to draw the segment $ [A,B] $ with only a ruler whose length is much smaller than the length of the segment.
I tried to construct a third point $ C $ between $ A $ and $ B $, but i can't figure out how to do.

Comment: Do you get a compass also, or just the short straightedge?  Also, is it an unmarked straightedge, or an actual ruler?

Comment: With the compass, it seems to be easy.

Comment: If you don't have a compass, I suspect you'll need a circle somewhere on the plane.

Comment: I think we need projective harmonic conjugates.

Comment: If you think this involves concepts that are more involved than plane geometry and have solved or seen similar questions that use them, then do mention them. I've seen similar problems and they do require a change of coordinates that isn't very obvious at a plane geometry level.  By the way, let me know if [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042541/how-can-we-draw-a-line-between-two-distant-points-using-a-finite-length-ruler) is a duplicate as well. It seems to work if you make "good enough approximations" (so it is not an algorithm , but works for sure).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks a lot for what you wrote. I appreciate.